# Wrong output of du?

Tags: disk-usage

I think my du command is confused.

```
% du -shc DIR ...
...
6123941496      total

% du -shc DIR ...
...
6.1G    total

% du -sc --si DIR ...
...
6.6G    total
```

I've tried giving `LANG=C` and double-checking the result in a spreadsheet. It looks like -h already outputs using powers of 1000 (--si), and --si gives wrong answer. I think the correct answer should be 5.7G for -h and 6.1G for --si. So what happens here?

```
% du --version
du (GNU coreutils) 8.20
...

% uname -a
Linux XXX 3.9-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.9.8-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please include the actual commands. What do the `...` represent? You seem to have run the exact same command twice and have gotten different output, is that so? Have you read the explanation of the size modifiers in `man du`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Repeat your tests using the `--apparent-size` switch.

```
$ du -shc --apparent-size DIR ...
```

*excerpt from du man page*

```
--apparent-size
       print  apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is
       usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in (`sparse') files, internal 
       fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
```

Comment: Ah, so apparently -b is equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'. I missed that. Using 'du -shc --apparent-size' now correctly gives 5.7G now. Thanks!

Comment: @GerryLufwansa - yeah when you start mixing in different filesystems or mounted CIFS ones it becomes really noticeable. I always use either `-b` or `--apparent-size`.

Comment: ... and the difference can get really huge with HSM systems, where migrated files report 0 (or something like a few kB) without `--apparent-size`.

Comment: Any solution for the `du` that comes with Mac OS X?